# How can I add a storyboard animation to my page resources in C#, then call it again later?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, animation, storyboard

HubPage is my landing page. On Hubpage.xaml, I have a grid of 3x3, containing a Rectangle, what I'm calling a "cell". In HubPage.xaml.cs, particularly in the HubPage() constructor, I create a storyboard for each cell:

```
CreateStoryboardForCell("Column0Row0");
CreateStoryboardForCell("Column0Row1");
...
CreateStoryboardForCell("Column2Row2");
```

I want to add a storyboard to the Page.Resources, normally I would do it in XAML, but I am attempting it from C#. Now, here is the CreateStoryboardForCell implementation:

```
    private void CreateStoryboardForCell(string cellName)
    {
        // Create two DoubleAnimations, one for scaleX and one for scaleY, and set their properties.
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2));
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();
        myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
        myDoubleAnimation2.Duration = duration;

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Duration = duration;

        sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
        sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation2);

        // Set the targets of the animations
        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, Column0Row0);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation2, Column0Row0);

        // Set the attached properties of ScaleX and ScaleY
        // to be the target properties of the two respective DoubleAnimations
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation1, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)");
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation2, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)");
        myDoubleAnimation1.To = 15;
        myDoubleAnimation2.To = 22;

        // Make the Storyboard a resource.
        try
        {
            pageRoot.Resources.Add("story" + cellName, sb);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Status.Text = "Error adding storyboard resource for cell" + cellName + ": " + e.Message;
        }
    }
```

pageRoot is from Hubpage.xaml: Page x:Name="pageRoot", etc. I do not get an exception when adding the resource, but I cannot see the resource when I set the breakpoint, so I assume it was added successfully, as I can see the count increasing, and no exception was thrown.

Moving on, I have a click handler for each column cell, where I infer the row and column number and try to start up the corresponding storyboard added to the page resource earlier. Here is the code:

```
    private void Column1_Cell_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Rectangle rect = sender as Rectangle;
        int x = (int)rect.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
        int y = (int)rect.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
        string storyboardName = "storyColumn" + y + "Row" + x;
        Storyboard storyboard = (Storyboard)FindName(storyboardName);

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

but the FindName call always returns a null storyboard. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written this code for you.I hope benefits to  business

Here is code:

```
   <Grid>       
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column0Row0"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column0Row1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column0Row2"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="Pink" x:Name="rectangle" MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="Coral" MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="2" Fill="Orange" MouseLeftButtonDown="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind :

```
private void CreateStoryboardForCell(Rectangle target)
    {
        ScaleTransform trans = new ScaleTransform();
        target.RenderTransform = trans;
        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(1, 2, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        trans.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, anim);
        trans.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, anim);

    }

    private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateStoryboardForCell((Rectangle)sender);            
    }
```

Comment: If you have another problems.I try to help

Comment: The error I get is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ScaleTransform' does not contain a definition for 'BeginAnimation' and no extension method 'BeginAnimation' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ScaleTransform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I think this is WPF and I need Windows Store app.

Comment: BeginAnimation did not work for me, but you set me along the right path, so I'm marking this as the answer. What I was doing wrong: saving a different StoryBoard for each target to App.Current.Resources, then retrieving on each target (Rectangle) click. Instead, I intercept the click, create the StoryBoard on the fly, and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.I always use this code for finding a storyboard.It works.

Here is code:

```
FrameworkElement element = new FrameworkElement();
Storyboard sb=new Storyboard ();
sb = element.FindResource("Please write here Storyboard Key") as Storyboard;
sb.Begin(target element name , true);
```

Comment: "Target element name" is the name of that you want to apply animate object. For example Ellipse object. x:Name="ellipse" . ellipse is the target element name. (Sorry I dont know very well English.I hope you got it)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your approach, but it seems FindResource is not available on WinRT.

Comment: If your style is defined in Resources of the App.xaml, you can use this code  var animation = Application.Current.Resources["ShowVideoCallPanel"] as Storyboard;

Comment: Resources["Storyboard Key"]

Comment: Storyboard sb=new Storyboard ();
sb = Application.Current.Resources["ShowVideoCallPanel"] as Storyboard;
sb.Begin(target element name , true);

Comment: I am adding the storyboard at runtime in C#, see the pageRoot.Resources.Add("story" + cellName, sb); call in the question.

Comment: Ok I replaced pageroot with Application.Current.Resources.Add and it worked perfectly, thank you. I ran into another issue, but I will ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If BeginStoryboard doesn't support in WinRT.You can use the following code.I created the animation in codedehind.Maybe you can solve the problem like this;I did some research on this problem.
I tried this code.It works

Here is code:

```
private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

        ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0);
        animatedRectangle.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        animatedRectangle.RenderTransform = scale;

        DoubleAnimation scaleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation(1, 2, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        DoubleAnimation scaleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation(1, 2, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        storyboard.Children.Add(scaleAnimation1);
        storyboard.Children.Add(scaleAnimation2);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimation2, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleY"));


        Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation1, animatedRectangle);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleAnimation2, animatedRectangle);

        storyboard.Begin();         

    }
```

Comment: Please take a look this web site http://irisclasson.com/2012/06/28/creating-a-scaletransform-animation-in-c-for-winrt-metro-apps/ in this web site there is a code called CompositeTransform.CompositeTransform used in winrt applications.I tried this code in Wpf application but didn't work.Because Composite transform doesn't supported in Wpf.

Comment: Please try the above code.If it doesn't work.You can take a look here "http://irisclasson.com/2012/06/28/creating-a-scaletransform-animation-in-c-for-winrt-metro-apps/" take it easy :)