# how to start animation using "caliburn micro 2" and "windows phone 8.1"

Tags: storyboard, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I am developing a bord game for *windows phone* using *caliburn micro v2*.

I want to start an animation when a stone is placed on the board.

I want to know **how to start an animation/storyboard** when in the viewmodel a stone changed event occurs.
I prefer the xaml is placed in the stone *style* because of the number of stones on the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call a storyboard from the viewmodel as suggested. The story is view specific and you will remove the testability and portability of your code.

You question is not very specific and there is no code example so it is not very easy to help but consider using a trigger to start your storyboard. This way you can keep it all in your view.

If you have a property in the viewmodel you can use a datatrigger to start the storyboard when it changes value. Maybe something similar to this

Import:

```
  xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
  xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
```

Example:

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding LoginPageIsEnabled}"
                               ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="False">
            <core:GoToStateAction StateName="Loading" />
        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding LoginPageIsEnabled}"
                               ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="True">
             <core:GoToStateAction StateName="DoneLoading" />
        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what i wanted to do. Except the DataTrigger does not work on windows phone 8.1. The DataTrigger is only working in Wpf.

Comment: I edited my answer so that it uses the datatriggers supported in wp8.1. I had problems finding them at first as well, microsoft removed datatriggers but you can use DataTriggerBehavior instead.

Comment: Please mark as answered if this helped or let me know what seems to be the problem

Comment: I had a silverlite app. And your solution didn't work. So I changed the app to a standard phone 8.1 app. After that change I had problems with the GUI. So now I am searching for a solution on a Silverlight 8.1 app.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done windows phone application before.But I'm using the following code in wpf applications

If your style is defined in Resources of the App.xaml, you can use this code

Here is code:

```
FrameworkElement element = new FrameworkElement();
Storyboard sb=new Storyboard ();
sb = element.FindResource("Please write here Storyboard Key") as Storyboard;
sb.Begin(target element name , true);
```

Please take a look at this link : [How can I add a storyboard animation to my page resources in C#, then call it again later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820227/how-can-i-add-a-storyboard-animation-to-my-page-resources-in-c-then-call-it-ag)
I hope it benefits to your business.

Comment: I see.Please take a look this site.There are several windows phone animation examples.Maybe benefits to your business. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: MLE, Thanks for your reply.
What I am looking for is a solution in xaml. With a binding to the viewmodel. In WPF I would do this with a DataTrigger but in Windows Phone 8.1 this is NOT supported.